# Custom url handler mapping for spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a HomePageController that serves content when user visits `www.medscape.com/news`. New requirement: if user visits `www.medscape.com/news` with cookie `rememberme`, serve different content. The logic is widely different for each of these workflows so it is better to send to a new controller HomePageRememberMeController(). How do you go about implementing this? Can a custom URL mapping handler be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily in one controller, even using one endpoint. Simply just implement one endpoint -> check the cookie -> if cookie is there call one private method that does what needs to be done otherwise call another method. I don't see any code in your question so don't really know on which point you got stuck, and nobody here will implement this based on vague specs.